# Quickest way to restrict a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, manifolds

Let $\phi: U \to V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphism.

*My desire is:*

I want to say the **restriction $\phi|_{\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x))}:\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x)) \to B_{r'}(x) $ is a homeomorphism** in the simplest way.

*My understanding is:*

Surjectivity) $\phi|_{\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x))} $ is surjective, since $\phi(\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x))) = B_{r'}(x)) $ (by surjectivity of $\phi$).

Injectivity) Clear.

**Continuity of $\phi$**)  First, $\phi|_{\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x))}:\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x)) \to V $ is continuous,

since inclusion map is continuous and $\phi|_{\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x))} = \phi \circ \iota_{\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x))} $

Second, $\phi|_{\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x))}:\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x)) \to B_{r'}(x) $ is continuous,

since taking any $V'$:open in $B_{r'}(x)$, then there is some $W$: open in $B_{r'}(x)$ s.t. $V' = B_{r'}(x) \cap W$.

$\phi^{-1}( B_{r'}(x) \cap W) = \phi^{-1}( (\iota_{B_{r'}(x)})^{-1}(W))$, which is open in U.

Similarly, $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous.

---

I think this proof is valid, but can we show the continuity in more straightforward way, without breaking down to restricting the domain and codomain? Thanks.

Comment: Restricting the domain and codomain is what your question is all about, so you cannot avoid that. While basically valid, your proof is clogged up by focussing on an inelegant special case and an inelegant definition of continuity...

Comment: … Instead of the open ball definition of continuity, use the open set definition: a function is continuous if and only if the inverse image of every open subset of the codomain is an open subset of the domain. Also, instead prove the general statement: if $f : U \to V$ is a homeomorphism of topological spaces then, for all subsets $B \subset V$, letting $A = f^{-1}(B)$, the restriction $\phi \bigm|_A : A \to B$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Mosher Thank you! I will equip the general statement.